# 3 value matchs 31 in loop - Python

Tags: python

This just a test for another script. I have this code that checks if a number in users file exists the value of the check function if it is then it prints the value. There's a problem with the `check` function if I add a value let's say `2` in the file example and to check if it exists in the `check(2)` it prints yes so when i add another value like 21 is still matches `2` and prints yes . I used regax but it dosen't help

```
    listNum = list(range(1, 101))
import re


def check(z):
    with open('users.txt') as f:
        file_content= f.read()
    for num in listNum: 
        array = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str(num))
        if str(z) in file_content:
            result = print("yes")
            return str(z)

check(1)
```

Comment: What is the point of `array` if you create it and then don't do anything with it.

Comment: @khelwood ah sorry about that, i edited which be like this but it doesn't print anything `if str(array) in file_content:`

Comment: if part is repeated 100 times ?

Comment: @pippo1980 The value in the users file is checked. What matches the numbers in the users file will be printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *way* overcomplicating this. Assuming the `users.txt` file contains only integers, each on its own line, then the following code prints "yes" if the test number is present in the file. Otherwise, nothing is printed. I'm not sure why your function returns a value when that value is not used.

```
def check(z):
    # z is the number you are checking the file for
    
    with open('users.txt') as f:
        # Remove the newline from each line in the file and convert the result into an integer
        file_content = [int(line.strip('\n')) for line in f.readlines()]
        
        # Does the number you're checking for exist in the list of numbers from the file?
        if z in file_content:  
            print('yes')

check(1)
```

Comment: Bro!! You don't know how much time I spent on this, you saved my life. Thank you!!!